# Pointers to array affecting wrong array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am having an  issue where editing array A is affecting array B in C when using pointers. My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "frac_heap.h"

#define ARRAYSIZE 10

fraction heap[][ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
block freeBlocks[][ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
int startingBlock = 0;

void init_Heap(){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x ++){    

        block *currBlock = freeBlocks[x];
        currBlock->isFree = 1;  
    }
}



void dump_heap(){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x ++){
        fraction* tempFrac = heap[x];
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",tempFrac->sign, tempFrac->numerator, tempFrac->denominator);
    }   
}


fraction* new_frac(){
    fraction* testFraction = heap[0];
    return testFraction;
}




int main(){ 
    init_Heap();
    dump_heap();
    fraction *p1;
    p1 = new_frac();
    p1->sign = -1;
    p1->numerator  = 2; 
    p1->denominator = 3;
    dump_heap();    
   }
```

dump_heap() just prints out the contents of heap along with the fractions sign, numerator, and denominator. However, the output when I run this code is the following:

```
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0

-1  2   3
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

See the 1s in the numerator place in numerous fractions in the fractions array even though I never told it to put 1s there? This doesnt happen if I edit out the call to init_heap(). If I edit out the call to init_heap the output is:

```
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0

-1  2   3
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

Which is correct. My question is why is init_heap affecting the fractions array even though in init_heap I am only editing and accessing the freeBlocks array?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to have an array of arrays? As it is now, `heap` (for example) is an array with a single entry, and that entry is an array of `ARRAYSIZE` fractions. This means you can't do e.g. `heap[x]` if `x` is larger than zero, as that will be out of bounds!

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare your arrays as `heap[][ARRAYSIZE]`, it doesn't make any sense, especially not in the way you are trying to use them. Instead, declared them as `heap[ARRAYSIZE]`.

Comment: write then instead `fraction* tempFrac = &heap[x];` or `fraction* tempFrac = heap + x;`

Answer (score 1):

From the way you're using them, it seems that `heap` and `freeBlocks` are meant to be 1D arrays, not 2D.

If that's the case, the following:

```
fraction heap[][ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
block freeBlocks[][ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
```

should become

```
fraction heap[ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
block freeBlocks[ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
```

Comment: Of course! Duh! I made this fix and now both arrays are printing out correctly. But regardless, how could this have caused the error I was experiencing?

Comment: @user2252004: You wrote past the allocated memory. Technically, this is undefined behaviour, but in practice you were just overwriting the memory that followed (i.e. the other array).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in these two definitions:

```
fraction heap[][ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
block freeBlocks[][ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
```

Each defines an array with size 1 for the leading dimension, because you only provide 1 initializer.

```
int x;
for (x = 0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x ++){    

    block *currBlock = freeBlocks[x];
    currBlock->isFree = 1;  
}
```

This code is indexing through the array of arrays one unit of 10 `block`s at a time (and is trampling way out of bounds).  `freeblocks[1]` is beyond the end of the space allocated for `freeblocks`; `freeblocks[9]` is even further out of control.